# MySQL - Counting transactions related to the most recent visit

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose I have two tables in the same MySQL DB:

The first is the inbound_campaign_visit table.  It looks like this.

```
+----+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id   | inbound_campaign | date                |
+----+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |                1 | 2013-02-18 13:00:00 |
|  2 |         1 |                2 | 2013-02-24 13:00:00 |
|  3 |         2 |                3 | 2013-01-01 01:00:00 |
|  4 |         2 |                2 | 2013-02-24 19:00:00 |
+----+-----------+------------------+---------------------+
```

A row on this table is generated every time a user visits my site as a result of clicking on a promotional campaign.  The "date" column represents the time when they came to the site.

The second table is my transaction table.

```
+--------+---------+---------------------+
| id     | user_id |    creation_date    |
+--------+---------+---------------------+
| 321639 |       1 | 2013-02-18 14:00:00 |
| 321640 |       1 | 2013-02-24 15:00:00 |
| 321641 |       1 | 2013-02-25 13:00:00 |
| 321642 |       1 | 2013-04-05 12:00:00 |
| 321643 |       2 | 2013-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 321644 |       2 | 2013-02-23 12:00:00 |
+--------+---------+---------------------+
```

A row on this table is created whenever a transaction happens.  The "creation_date" column represents the time the transaction occured.

I want to create a report that will count the number of transactions per inbound campaign.  The following rules must apply:

1. A transaction is considered related to an inbound campaign if the user_id values match that of the transaction and the transaction occurred within 30 days of an inbound_campaign_visit row being created.
2. A transaction can only apply to the most recent inbound campaign_visit for the given user.

The result table should look something like this:

```
+------------------+-------------------+
| inbound_campaign | transaction_count |
+------------------+-------------------+
|                1 |                 1 |
|                2 |                 2 |
|                3 |                 1 |
+------------------+-------------------+
```

Notice that transactions 321644 and 321642 are not counted as they fail rule 1.  Also notice how transaction 321641 only applies to inbound_campaign 2 and not inbound_campaign 1 (even though both campaigns fall within the 30 day restriction defined in rule 1).

I have been struggling with this for some time so any help would be appreciated.  Of course I could do this in code but there must be a way to do this in SQL.  TIA.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.inbound_campaign,
        COUNT(b.user_ID) TotalCount
FROM    inbound_campaign_visit a
        LEFT JOIN transaction b
            ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
               DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), b.creation_date) > 30
GROUP   BY a.inbound_campaign
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8629/10)

Comment: That seems to work on the example I provided but breaks down when I start adding more transactions.  In example if I add the following row to transaction "(321645, 2, '2013-01-02 12:00:00')" the results will be 1, 3, 2 in the right column.  They should be 1, 2, 2.  I am also curious how this query honors rule number 2 mentioned above.